# Generated vs Generation (vs Procedural-Generation and Content-Generation)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Prompted by [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53190/improving-my-roguelike-dungeon-generator) over on main, there seems to be a lot of redundancy/confusion around these tags.  I feel like both 'Generated' and 'Generation' are probably bad tags as neither suggests either what is being generated or how, merely that something is being generated; my inclination would be to throw them both out in favor of the more descriptive 'Procedural Generation' and 'Content Generation' tags.  Any other thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

I just went ahead and removed the generated/generation tags from most questions in lieu of [procedural-generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedural-generation).  In the cases where prodecural generation didn't make sense I just removed the tag since it wasn't really descriptive enough.